# Split columns by number in a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, split

I'm trying to separate a column in a rather untidy dataframe.

```
section
View 500
V458
453
```

And I want to create a new column from this. With the preferred output like below.

```
section  section numbers  
View     500
V        458
         453
```

I've been trying to research it but I'm having a time with it.  I can separate them in the case of the first row, because I can use regex like this.

```
df_split <- separate(df, col = section, into = c("section", "section_number"), sep = " +[1-9]")
```

But I can't seem to find a way to use an "or" type statement. If anyone has any input that would be wonderful.

Comment: `"\\s*(?=\\d)"` PCRE regex might help here.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I meant something like `do.call(rbind, str_split(df$section, '\\s*(?=\\d)', 2))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a simple `gsub` would be a choice for me:

```
section <- c('View 500', 'V458', '453')

cbind(section = trimws(gsub('[0-9]', '', section)), 
      section_numbers = trimws(gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', section)))
```

I use `trimws` to just remove any unwanted white spaces.

Output:

```
    section section_numbers
[1,] "View"  "500"          
[2,] "V"     "458"          
[3,] ""      "453"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tidyr` for this:

```
tidyr::extract(df,section, c("section", "section number"), 
               regex="([[:alpha:]]*)[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]*)")
  section section number
1    View            500
2       V            458
3                    453
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extract` which also comes from the `tidyr` package, with which you can specify the capture group, make them optional here and it is pretty flexible to handle different cases:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% extract(section, into = c("alpha", "numeric"), regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)?\\s?(\\d+)?")

#  alpha numeric
#1  View     500
#2     V     458
#3  <NA>     453
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R` with `read.csv` and `sub`.  We capture the numbers at the end as a group (`(\\d+)$`) and replace with a comma and the backreference for the group (`\\1`) in the `sub`, and read it with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text=sub("\\s*(\\d+)$", ",\\1", df1$section), fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, 
         col.names = c("section", "section number"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#   section section.number
#1    View            500
#2       V            458
#3                    453
```

Answer (score 0):

with `stringr` (assuming the original `df` has just one column named `section`):

```
library(stringr)
df_split <- as.data.frame(str_match(df$section, "([A-Za-z]*)\\s*([0-9]*)")[,2:3])
names(df_split) <- c('section', 'section numbers')
df_split

#  section section numbers
#1    View             500
#2       V             458
#3                     453
```